# ValidationError: File validation failed: filename: Path `filename` is required., path: Path `path` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

in this project, I try to upload a file. from frontend to backend, and save that file, the error showing like this,

***error***

> > > the error

```
this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
                               ^

ValidationError: File validation failed: filename: Path `filename` is required., path: Path `path` is required.
    at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\FILE-SHARING-APP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2970:32)        
    at C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\FILE-SHARING-APP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2759:17
    at C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\FILE-SHARING-APP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1333:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  errors: {
    filename: ValidatorError: Path `filename` is required.
        at validate (C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\FILE-SHARING-APP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1330:13)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\FILE-SHARING-APP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1314:7)
        at C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\FILE-SHARING-APP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2751:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
      properties: {
        validator: [Function (anonymous)],
        message: 'Path `filename` is required.',
        type: 'required',
        path: 'filename',
        value: undefined
      },
```

> > > here ,  for unique file Name  i used  uuid  and i given   storege,
> > > limit:{fileSize:100000*100},
> > > ***the requirement is I need to upload any file and I generate the link for that file for download that file***

***fails.js***

```
const router = require ('express').Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const File =require('../models/file');
const {v4 : uuid4} =require('uuid')


 let storege = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cd) =>cd(null,'uploads/'),

 // for unique file Name  

     filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        const uniqueName =`${Date.now()}-${Math.round(Math.random()*1E9)}${this.path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null,uniqueName);
     }
  }) 

  let upload =multer({
    storege,
    limit:{fileSize:100000*100},
  }).single('myfiles');


router.post('/' ,(req,res)=>{
  //store files:
        upload(req,res,async(error)=>{
   //validate require
     if(!req.file){
       return res.json({error:'All files are required.'})
           }

            if (error){
             return res.status(500).send({error:error.message})
            }
  // store into Database:
        const file = new File({
         filename: req.file.filename,
         uuid:uuid4(),
         path:req.file.path,
         size:req.file.size,
         
        });
        const response = await file.save();
        return res.json({file:`${process.env.APP_BASE_URL}/files/${response.uuid}`});
        //http://localhost:3000/files/2433r4r4t444r3-3r3r
        });
   

    //Respone ->Link

})

module.exports=router;
```

> > > here is the mongoose. Schema has filename, path, size, uuid, sender  and  resiver is false

***file.js***

```
 const  mongoose = require ('mongoose');
    
    const Schema =mongoose.Schema;
    
    const filesSchema = new Schema({
        filename:{type:String,required:true},
        path:{type:String,required:true},
        size:{type:Number,required:true},
        uuid:{type:String,required:true},
       sender:{type:String,required:false},
      resiver:{type:String,required:false},
    },{ timestamps:true});
    module.exports=mongoose.model('File',filesSchema)
```

> > > the error shows like  :
> > > my Requirement needs to upload any file means .jpg, png, or pdf.

```
 this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
                               ^
ValidationError: File validation failed: path: Path `path` is required.
```

how to fix this error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out for myself what the error was. This is an error caused by a small mistake. the mistake is in ***fails.js***

```
 // for unique file Name  

     filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        const uniqueName =`${Date.now()}-${Math.round(Math.random()*1E9)}${this.path.extname(file.originalname)}`;
        cb(null,uniqueName);
     }
```

> > > in this Piece of code has a problem. `${this.path.extname(file.originalname)}`;` here noneed to add ***this.path***
> > > only need to use ***${path.extname(file.originalname)}***  Actually this is a mistake that came to me unknowingly.